# Alternate ways to filling forms in Selenium?

Tags: python, forms, selenium

I am using Python and Selenium to fill out a form quickly. It can fill out everything except for the telephone number and credit card number. I am using

```
driver.find_element_by_id("order_tel").send_keys(telInfo.get())
```

And

```
driver.find_element_by_id("cnb").send_keys(numberInfo.get())
```

I fill out everything else the same way, and it works. The only difference with these two is that the entry form is pre-formatted. Here is a photo of the [telephone entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90TGv.png). The same is with the credit card. I can paste into them, but the send_keys command just isn't working.

So are there any workarounds/ alternate ways to fill out this form?

Comment: You can have a look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419339/not-able-to-input-date-using-sendkeys-in-selenium-webdriver) solution already on stackoverflow

Comment: Those do not work,I tried removing the read-only attribute but it just stops at the telephone numberr

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Answer (score 0):

I already encountered problem like this. I don't really know python, but I will try to put an example :

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsById('order_tel').value='myText'")
```

I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try calling the clear() method first before sending the keys?