# Python - Selenium - Two equal website imput boxes, one works with send_keys(), the other doesnt

Tags: python, selenium, textinput

I'm using Python 3.7 and Selenium, trying to imput a date and a time into two apparently identical text input boxes in a website, using send_keys().

The Time input box works fine, send_keys('00:00:00') writes the time as needed.

The Date input box does not react, no matter what formatting I try to send the string with. I've tried adding a .click(), .clear(), Keys.HOME, before writing, to no avail.

I dont know what the difference is.

```
startTimeBox = browser.find_element_by_name('TimeStart')
startTimeBox.get_attribute('outerHTML')
Out[187]: '<input name="TimeStart" id="TimeStart" title="Please enter start time" size="10" maxlength="12" value="00:00:00" type="time">'

startDateBox = browser.find_element_by_name('DateStart')
startDateBox.get_attribute('outerHTML')
Out[185]: '<input name="DateStart" id="DateStart" title="Please enter start date" size="10" maxlength="11" value="09/11/2018" style="" type="date">'
```

Well, looking at this side by side I noticed the "style" part that's present in the date box. I guess that might influence it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419339/not-able-to-input-date-using-sendkeys-in-selenium-webdriver/52754856#52754856

Comment: ... and some context: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1070

Answer (score 0):

As JacobIRR mentioned in the comments, there could be a problem with Firefox Driver instead use Chrome driver or click the field before sending keys.

The solution to this is to try using `click()` before sending keys.